# audio.js player not loading in IE 9 and below

Tags: javascript, html, audiojs

The audio.js player is not loading in Internet Explorer 9. When I use mp3/ogg/wav format, they all show the same error:

```
Error loading: "[object Object]"
```

[image]

However, it does work on Chrome and Firefox. This is the code I'm using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="./audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
<script>
  audiojs.events.ready(function() {
    audiojs.createAll();
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<audio src="ace.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Someone on github had the same issue. Try this: https://github.com/kolber/audiojs/commit/e15fb78b11f04f9fc4c40fb2e017659c6aa7b0e9

Comment: hmm .. whenever i change my `<script src="../audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>` to   `<script src="../audiojs/audio.js"></script>` will have error message : 'audiojs' is undefined. So i included both of them, still same loading error.

Comment: What else have you tried doing to solve the issue?

Comment: No idea :(, i just copy the demo file, audio file and includes file then edited the audio.js based on the link you gave. after that i try run it, still having the same issue. Perhaps any others audio player that can support  >= IE8/9 ?

Comment: Picture changed, the picture is after I used the code from the github site.

Comment: regarding your answer, you can use [soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) library, has also html5 support.

Answer (score 0):

You should first look in the network-tab of the developertools and check that the audio-files is loaded. I did get the same error for videos and i had to extend the mineTypes for the IE.

Try to extend your .htaccess with

```
# Server can play audio
# MP3 audio
AddType audio/mpeg3 .mp3
AddType audio/mp3 .mp3
AddType audio/x-mpeg3 .mp3

# Ogg Vorbis audio
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/ogg .oga
```

The IE needs the right application-header, chrome and firefox are smart enough in the most cases.

Comment: Hi, sorry .. May i know how to extend .htaccess ?

Comment: In the root directory of your website should be a .htaccess file. Extend this file with the lines i write in the post.

Did this help you?